# Solving a differential equation with the heaviside unit step function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

[image]

I am having trouble figuring out what exactly to do for this question. Given the initial conditions y(0)=1 and the equation y'-2y=4-3u(t-2) where u is the heaviside unit step function. I took the Laplace of both sides and got: sy(s)-1+2y(s)= 4/s - L{3u(t-2)}. I know that the left side simplifies to: (s+2)y(s) but I am not sure how to simplify L{3u(t-2)}.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the integral definition of the Laplace transform for this function? It simplifies to a nice form.

Answer (score 1):

Since $u(t-2)=0$ for $t<2$, but $1$ for $t>2$,
$$\mathcal{L}(3u(t-2)) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}3 \cdot u(t-2) \; dt$$
$$=3\int_2^\infty e^{-st} \; dt$$
$$=-\left.\frac{e^{-st}}{s}\right|_2^\infty$$
$$=\frac{e^{-2s}}{s}$$

Comment: You introduce an extraneous t in your first integral and end up with the wrong answer (check wolfram)

Comment: @clubsandwedge Oops, I have absolutely no idea how that got there. The integral would be much easier in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Can work it out using the following idea (split the integral):

$L\{u(t-2)\} = \int_0^\infty{u(t-2)e^{-st}dt} = \int_0^2{u(t-2)e^{-st}dt}  + \int_2^\infty{u(t-2)e^{-st}dt} = \int_2^\infty{e^{-st}dt} = \ldots = \frac{e^{-2s}}{s}$